# Received the integer type of LinkedHashMap from the long type of HashMap?

Tags: spring-cloud

I use Edgware.SR5 version of spring cloud framework, 1.5.9.RELEASE version of spring boot framework, and the service provider interacts with consumers using the `List<Map<String, Object>` return value result set. The problem is that the long in `Map<String, Object>` is converted to integer, that is, `result.get(0).get("count").getClass()` is the integer type from the long at the service provider to the service consumer. How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Here's the service provider

```java
@GetMapping("/report/common/data/search")
public List<Map<String, Object>> searchSaleReport(@RequestParam("param") String param) {
    return saleReportService.searchSaleReport(param); 
    //The type of attribute count value provided in HashMap is long.
}
```

[image]

Here are the service consumers

```java
@FeignClient("${sale.feign.name}")
public interface SaleReportService {
    @GetMapping("/report/common/data/search")
    List<Map<String, Object>> searchSaleReport(@RequestParam("param") String param); 
    //The type of count value of the attribute in consumer LinkedHashmap is Integer.
}
```

[image]

Service provider `result.get(0).get("count").getClass()` is of long type, 
Service consumer `result.get(0).get("count").getClass()` is of integer type.

Comment: I answered on github, I won't respond here.

Comment: Can you provide a link to github's answer? Thank you